# CI2CV build error with Cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am trying to build [CIC2V face tracking library](http://face.ci2cv.net) using `Cmake` on windows.
I am getting the following error

> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with
>   any  of the following names:
>
> OpenCVConfig.cmake
>      opencv-config.cmake

here is what I am typing in the cmd:

```
cmake DOpenCV_PREFIX=D:\opencv\build ..
```

the directory `D:\opencv\build` contains a file OpenCVConfig.cmake but still `cmake` is giving the same error.

any ideas ?

Comment: -DOpenCV_PREFIX=D:\opencv\build (you lost the 'hyphen')

Comment: it worked, can you write it as an answer please so I can mark the question as solved

Comment: were you ever able to compile this with windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you lost the hyphen at the beginning of the cmake define, it should be :

```
cmake -DOpenCV_PREFIX=D:\opencv\build ..
```

------------^